# Changing layout - widgets in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

This is my first trial in PyQt5 (no previous experience in creating GUI in Python, but I have written a few programs using Python). My problem is changing window content after a button click. I have created my main class:

```
class GUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.psuE3631A = E3631A()
        self.init_gui()

    def init_gui(self):
        self.initGUI = initGUI(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Control panel - E3631A')
        self.centralWidget.addWidget(self.initGUI)
        self.show()

    def simple_gui(self):
        self.simpleGUI = simpleGUI(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Control panel - E3631A')
        self.centralWidget.addWidget(self.simpleGUI)
        self.centralWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.simpleGUI)
        self.show()

    def advanced_gui(self):
        pass

    def close_window(self):
        print_comment("Exit application")
        self.close()
```

and I am trying to switch beetwen initGUI and simpleGUI.

**simpleGUI:**

```
class simpleGUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(simpleGUI, self).__init__(parent)

        print_comment("GUI in simple mode!")

        layout = QGridLayout()
        btn_close = QPushButton("&Exit app", self)
        btn_close.clicked.connect(self.parent().close_window)

        layout.addWidget(btn_close, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(btn_close, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(btn_close, 2, 0)
        layout.addWidget(btn_close, 2, 2)
        self.setLayout(layout)
```

**initGUI:**

```
class initGUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(initGUI, self).__init__(parent)

        self.psuE3631A = self.parent().psuE3631A

        print_comment("GUI initialize mode!")
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.ComboBoxPorts = QComboBox(self)
        self.ComboBoxPorts.setToolTip("Select port to connect with device - only psu E3631A will be connected!")
        self.init_comboBoxPorts()
        self.scan_ports()

        lbl_version = QLabel("ver " + VERSION)
        lbl_version.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
        btn_refresh = QPushButton("&Refresh ports", self)
        btn_refresh.clicked.connect(self.refresh_port_list)
        self.btn_connect = QPushButton("&Connect", self)
        self.btn_connect.clicked.connect(self.connect_to_device)
        btn_close = QPushButton("&Exit app", self)
        btn_close.clicked.connect(self.parent().close_window)
        if USER is "ADVANCED":
            cb_preselect = QCheckBox("Preselect")
            cb_preselect.stateChanged.connect(self.check_preselect)
            layout.addWidget(cb_preselect, 3, 0)

        layout.addWidget(lbl_version, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.ComboBoxPorts, 2, 0)
        layout.addWidget(btn_refresh, 2, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn_connect, 2, 2)
        layout.addWidget(btn_close, 3, 2)

        self.setLayout(layout)
```

I am not sure if the above code format is good, so here is a direct link to my [git repo](https://github.com/Nichten93/E3631A-GUI) (there is rest of function and files)

This is what I get:

[image: GUI layout error]

What am I doing wrong that in simpleGUI, there is only one button and it is not in the correct position? Am I using `QStackedWidget()` correctly? I suppose that is my problem, but after a lot of trials, I have no idea how to fix this...

Comment: The indentation in your code samples is incorrect.

Comment: I think they are correct, but I can not format it correctly on stackoverflow - sorry for that. This code is working one.

Comment: Why can't you? indentation is critical with python. We can only go by what we see.

Comment: I think that now it should be ok - on github repo code is correct

Comment: What you are doing wrong in the simpleGUI is multiple call to `addWidget` function with the same object `btn_close`. The Qt takes into account only your first call, all following calls are omitted (therefor the button is at position `0, 1`). If you want multiple buttons in the GUI, you need multiple instances of the `QPushButton` class.

Comment: Ok, and how to fix size of buttons? In initGUI they have default size and in simpleGUI it seems that window size is fixed and width of buttons is changing while in initGUI window size is automatically adjusted. And question about `QStackedWidget()` - should I call setCurrentWidget after initGUI creation?

Comment: I do not understand what your problem is, I have tried your code and I see that you have changed your eyesight, what do you want to get?

Comment: Why do you add the same button several times to the layout? `layout.addWidget(btn_close, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(btn_close, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(btn_close, 2, 0)
        layout.addWidget(btn_close, 2, 2)`

Comment: The `QStackedWidget` is not used in the correct way. Add all the widgets you need in the `GUI.__init__`. Then only call either `setCurrentIndex` or `setCurrentWidget` in the `init_gui` and `simple_gui` functions.